# How do I wait for a background process to complete?

Tags: shell, process, variable, background-process

I'm using Amazon Linux with bash shell.  I would like to run a couple of processes in the background, and then wait for them to complete (either with a success or error exit code) before proceeding.  So I tried:

```
node test.js 2>&1 | tee --append $TFILE1 &
proc1=$!
node SkyLocal.js 2>&1 | tee --append $TFILE2 &
proc2=$!

wait proc1
rc1=$?
wait proc2
rc2=$?
```

but I'm getting these errors:

```
/home/jboss/.jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace/automated-tests/nodejs/run_tests.sh: line 36: wait: `proc1': not a pid or valid job spec
/home/jboss/.jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace/automated-tests/nodejs/run_tests.sh: line 38: wait: `proc2': not a pid or valid job spec
```

How do I capture the PID of the background process and then wait for the process to complete before continuing?

Comment: `wait $proc1` Don't forget the dollar sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error messages hint, the `wait` command won't try to look up the pid by the variable name for you (although as a built-in, it could theoretically do it).

You need to pass `wait` the actual pid values (or job numbers) as stored in the proc1 and proc2 variables. You do that by prepending `$` to the variable names as usual. That will cause the shell to substitute the values for the variable names before passing them on to the `wait` command.